# HTML table data wrap

Tags: html

As the default behavior of a html table data  is wrap the data right? But my table cell data does not wrap and when i add long text the whole table getting expand.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean long text as in one long string?  Like this:
"askjdklasjdklasjdlkasjd"
or do you mean a long amount of text with spaces between words?
Also, have you set a width on the table?

Comment: exactly Munzilla..long text with no space..if we have at least a one space its automatically get wrap

Answer (score 2):

This one will help you...

[How to prevent HTML tables from becoming too wide](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200704/how_to_prevent_html_tables_from_becoming_too_wide/)

Use `table-layout:fixed` and set a width for your table.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the css style word-break: break-all;